# JQuery need help in coding

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the code that I need to add here so the game will restart if the hero touches the wall. I need some help.

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/bg.jpg";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.jpg";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/monster.jpg";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};
addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a monster
var reset = function () {
    hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
    hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

    // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
    monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));

};

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
    hero.x <= (monster.x + 32) && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32) && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32) && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)) {
        ++monstersCaught;
        reset();
    }
};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
    if (heroReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }
    if (monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }

    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Goblins caught: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    update(delta / 1000);
    render();
    then = now;
    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

Comment: can you put this in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: i didn't know how to use it sorry :(

Comment: Hello @KcirdezOinotna when you state `wall` in your question, where is your wall class? What do you mean by wall?

Comment: i mean the side of the canvas. @Canvas

Comment: @canvas the code is useful, thanks. The only now i need to think is the score reset ^_^

Comment: @KcirdezOinotna If the code I provided is correct please accept the answer :)

Comment: @Canvas hows the code of the reset?

Comment: @KcirdezOinotna make a new function called `reset` and inside of that function you just reset the values for your hero and monsters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the player is outside of the canvas you can do something like this

```
if( hero.x < -32 || hero.x > canvas.width + 32 || hero.y < -32 || hero.y > canvas.height + 32)
{
    reset();
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work, you will need to put this function inside of your gameloop. To reset your score, just update your `reset` function to set the variable `score = 0;` You will of course first need to create a new variable called `score` :)